# I want to selected data from an XML file where element is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, gridview

This is the code that I have worked out, but I don't know how to put the selected data into a gridview in C#.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(savePath);
XElement ele = doc.Root.Element("boatInSlip");

var addSlipToGrid = from slip in doc.Elements("slipList").Elements("slip")
                            where slip.Element("boatInSlip").Value == ""
                            select slip;
        foreach (var slip in addSlipToGrid)
        {
            //No idea what needs to come into here
            //(EDIT) This code seemed to put 1 char in each cell
            nullSlipGrid.DataSource = slip.Value;
            nullSlipGrid.DataBind();
        }
```

This is the XML data.

```
<slipList>
  <slip>
    <dock>Dock 1</dock>
<slipId>2</slipId>
<slipWidth>4</slipWidth>
<slipLength>12</slipLength>
<boatInSlip></boatInSlip>
<slipHeight>12</slipHeight>
<slipDoor>true</slipDoor>
  </slip>
</slipList>
```

I want to select all the 'slips' where 'boatInSlip' = "" and display them into the gridview nullSlipGrid.

(EDIT 1) This result was displayed in a gridview in 1 column downwards:
D
o
c
k

1
2
4
1
2
1
2
t
r
u
e

Comment: Does your query work?  Are you not getting the data you expect or is it throwing an error?

Comment: It worked in previous classes when I remove an element eg. customer.remove() within the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the `xml` in `DataSet`which will be converted in `DataTables` and you can assign `DataTable` as `DataSource` to your `girdview`.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(savePath);

nullSlipGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
nullSlipGrid.DataBind();
```

Comment: however, I dont want to load the entire xml file. Only the "slip" where 'boatInSlip' == "".

Comment: @JohnNicolay than you have to create a custom class and manually loop through the nodes and create objects of your class. And than assign that to gridview

Comment: That (IMO) is an ugly way to deal with XML when you have LINQ to XML available.

Comment: @MairajAhmad - For what OP is looking for, LINQ to XML would seem to be a better approach.